# Sink events of a same Kafka topic into multiple paths in GCS

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am using the Schema Registry with `RecordNameStrategy` naming policy so I have events with totally different avro schemas into the same Kafka topic.

I am doing that as I want to group logically related events that may have different data structures under a same topic to keep order for these data.

For instance:
`user_created` event and `user_mail_confirmed` event might have different schemas but it's important to keep them into a same topic partition to guarantee order for consumers.

I am trying to sink these data, coming from a single topic, into GCS in multiple paths (one path for each schema)

Does someone know if the Confluent Kafka connect GCS Sink connector (or any other connector) provide us with that feature please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used GCS connector, but I suppose that this is not possible with Confluent connectors in general.

You should probably copy your source topic with different data structures to a new set of topics, where data have common data structure. This is possible with ksqlDB (check an [example](https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/data-routing/)) or Kafka Streams application. Then, you can create connectors for these topics.

Alternatively, you can use [RegexRouter](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html) transformation with a set of predicates based on the message headers.